# Adding email to CNMutableContact error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontactstore

I am trying to use the following code to add an email to my contact information to store it on the local device, unfortunately the code is crashing the app. How can I go about fixing this? I can see nothing online in `Objective-C` all examples are in `Swift`

```
CNLabeledValue *mailtest = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelWork value:@"curtis.boylan@gmail.com"];
contact.emailAddresses = mailtest;
```

Comment: What is the exception message or crash details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`emailAddresses` is of type `NSArray<CNLabelledValue<NSString *> *>`.

Even though you are only adding a single email address, you must put it in an array to assign to that property.

```
CNLabeledValue *mailtest = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelWork value:@"curtis.boylan@gmail.com"];
contact.emailAddresses = @[mailtest];
```